# What does -u do in the command line?

Tags: command-line

I've been seeing '-u' used a lot in command line and I'd like to know what it does. For example, when it's used in:

```
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: What it does, if it does anything at all, depends on the program you are running. Tip: `man git` and `man mysql`

Comment: That comment is definetly the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes means **user**, but each program sets whatever it want.